# Dynamically format columns on Workbook.OpenText using FieldInfo in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm writing a program in VBA to `open` a text file. I want to `format` the cells to text `on open` to perserve data (issue: long number strings are being converted to numbers and truncate).

Through research I've learned this can be done using the `FieldInfo` argument for `.OpenText`.

All current examples working on the internet are static and require the programmer to hard code in `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1,2),Array(2,2).....Array(n,2)`.

Here is the closest I got to an answer but this doesn't work either.
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/522433-workbooks-opentext-method-fieldinfo-parameter.html. It gives me a `1004` error.
Here is my version:

```
Dim colInfo(1 To 1000,1 To 2)
For i = 1 To 1000
    colInfo(i , 1) = i
    colInfo(i , 2) = 2
Next i
```

I can't find any vba documentation on `Array`. If I could figure out how to create an `Array` variable NOT a `Dim x() As y`, I could solve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a lot of discussion (and perhaps a fix for you?) here: http://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array function just returns a variant - it is just a quick way of initialising.  So you could just create one of those instead and pass that in as your argument.  For example:

```
Sub abc()

Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant

v1 = Array(1, 2, 3)

ReDim v2(3)
v2(0) = 1
v2(1) = 2
v2(2) = 3

MsgBox v1(0) & vbTab & v2(0) & vbCr & v1(1) & vbTab & v2(1) & vbCr & v1(2) & vbTab & v2(2)

End Sub
```

These two arrays (v1 and v2) are the same.

I hope this helps.