# How to programatically define FieldInfo parameter on Workbooks.OpentText in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

The Workbooks.OpenText method takes a parameter called FieldInfo to determine the format types in each column. For example the following code will open a text file and give Columns 1 and 2 a Text format, and Column 3 a General format.

```
Workbooks.OpenText fileName:="C:\somefile.txt", _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 1))
```

Let's say at runtime I determine that my text file has 4 columns and columns 2 and 4 should be text. How can I pass that in programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel):

> ### **`FieldInfo`** <sub><sup>*(optional, Variant)*</sup></sub>
>
> An [array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-arrays) containing parse information for individual columns of data. The interpretation depends on the value of [`DataType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/xltextparsingtype-enumeration-excel). When the data is [delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter), this argument is an array of two-element arrays, with each two-element array specifying the conversion options for a particular column.
>
> - the **first element** is the ***column number*** (1-based), and,
> - the **second element** is one of the [***XlColumnDataType***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlcolumndatatype-enumeration-excel) constants specifying how the column is parsed.

---

> ### **`XlColumnDataType` Enumeration**
>
> ```
>    Constant         Value    Description       
>  ----------------- ------- ----------------------- 
>   xlDMYFormat           4   DMY date format.       
>   xlDYMFormat           7   DYM date format.       
>   xlEMDFormat          10   EMD date format.       
>   xlGeneralFormat       1   General.               
>   xlMDYFormat           3   MDY date format.       
>   xlMYDFormat           6   MYD date format.       
>   xlSkipColumn          9   Column is not parsed.  
>   xlTextFormat          2   Text.                  
>   xlYDMFormat           8   YDM date format.       
>   xlYMDFormat           5   YMD date format.
> ```

With your data, if columns 2 and 4 should be `Text`, those would be:

```
Array(2,2) 
Array(4,2)
```

You didn't specify columns 1 and 3, so if they were `General` then the entire array would be:

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1,1), Array(2,2), Array(3,1),Array(4,2))
```

...or alternatively, for clarity, you could use:

```
FieldInfo:=Array( _
                  Array(1,xlGeneralFormat), _
                  Array(2,xlTextFormat), _
                  Array(3,xlGeneralFormat), _
                  Array(4,xlTextFormat) _
                )
```

---

> ### Notes:
>
> - The column specifiers can be in **any order**. If there's no column specifier for a particular column in the input data, the column is parsed with the General setting.
> - If the source data has **fixed-width** columns, *the first element in each two-element array specifies the position of the starting character* in the column (as an integer; character `0` (zero) is the first character). The second element in the two-element array specifies the parse option for the column as a number between `0` and `9`, as listed in the preceding table.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Workbooks.OpenText` Method** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel)
- MSDN : [**`xlColumnDataType` Enumeration** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlcolumndatatype-enumeration-excel)

Answer (score 2):

You can build your FieldInfo Array at runtime.

```
Private Function GetFieldInfo(nFields as Integer)
    Dim colInfo(1 to nFields, 1 to 2)

    For i = 1 to nFields

        colInfo(i,1) = i
        If (i = 2) Or (i = 4) Then
            ' Text format for columns 2 and 4
            colInfo(i,2) = xlTextFormat
        Else
            colInfo(i,2) = xlGeneralFormat
        End If
    Next i
    GetFieldInfo = colInfo
End Function

Workbooks.OpenText fileName:="C:\somefile.txt", FieldInfo:=GetFieldInfo(4)
```

In [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350719/dynamically-format-columns-on-workbook-opentext-using-fieldinfo-in-vba) there is a similar answer.

Comment: 2K exactly, congrats (proof [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4a2E.png)) ..  now I'll have to ruin that nice, round number by upvoting...

Comment: fantastic, thanks - I needed a solution to be able to set one single field (of >350) to Text to avoid something which looked like a number from being converted to scientific notation